# overwriting + function with custom function in Julia

Tags: julia

I try to implement a custom addition (and substraction) function in Julia for created types

```
import Base: *, +, -

function +(in1::MyType,in2::MyType)
    if condition_met
        return 2*in1
    else
        return in1 + in2
    end
end

-(in1::MyType,in2::MyType) = in1 + -1*in2
```

that works fine for the case when the condition is met, but of course it leads to an infinite loop for the case when the condition is not met (since it will invoke the function again). Is there an (elegant) way to circumvent this problem?

Comment: What is `MyType` and how is `*(::Int,::MyType)` implemented? Presumably `MyType` has some member value in it that is used in that multiplication. Can you provide those definitions?

Comment: it is a bit hard to give a minimum working example since I try to implement another method in an already existing bigger project. The relevant code where I want to add some 'custom' addition is here https://github.com/qojulia/QuantumCumulants.jl/blob/master/src/indexing.jl#L306

Comment: What do you want to happen in the `else` case? If it's something like `MyType(in1.val + in2.val)` then you have to write that, `+` can't guess. 

Or perhaps the example is too simplified. The words sound a bit like you are looking for `invoke` / `@invoke`, for calling an existing more-generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example implementation

```
struct MyType
    val::Float64
end

function Base.:+(x::MyType, y::MyType)
    if x.val > 100
        return MyType(2 * x.val)
    else
        return MyType(x.val + y.val)
    end
end
Base.:-(x::MyType) = MyType(-x.val)
Base.:-(x::MyType, y::MyType) = x + (-y)
```

Using it:

```
julia> x = MyType(2.0)
MyType(2.0)

julia> y = MyType(3.0)
MyType(3.0)

julia> z = MyType(103.0)
MyType(103.0)

julia> x + y
MyType(5.0)

julia> x - y
MyType(-1.0)

julia> z + y
MyType(206.0)

julia> y + z
MyType(106.0)
```